# Converting from HttpClient 3 to 4

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I've managed to make changes to everything but the following:

```
HttpClient client;
HttpPost method;   
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
method = new HttpPost(url); 

InputStream rstream;
try {
    rstream = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
    return BadSpot(e.getMessage()); 
}
```

What I'm not sure of is what I should replace getResponseBodyAsStream() with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
InputStream rstream;
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(HttpHost, method);
    rstream = response.getEntity().getContent();
} catch (IOException e) {
    return BadSpot(e.getMessage()); 
}
```

above should do what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

[HttpResponse.getEntity()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getEntity%28%29), followed by [HttpEntity.getContent()](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContent%28%29)

Answer (score 2):

The util class has some helpful methods:

```
EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

There is also some useful stuff in the examples at [apache's website](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `EntityUtils` and check the returned entity to be `not null` before consuming the entity:

```
InputStream rstream;
try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(HttpHost, method);

    rstream = Optional.ofNullable(httpResponse.getEntity())
    .map(e -> response.getContent()).orElse(null);

} catch (IOException e) {
    return BadSpot(e.getMessage()); 
}
```

**NOTE:** the InputStream here can be null and most of all you have to ensure that it's consumed before you actually close the response/release the connection.