# import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*

Tags: java

I use a code that imports the following package:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
```

I use eclipse. I went to http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi & I downloaded the Jar files, I added them to my project. Still eclipse making an error for this.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:     HttpClient cannot be resolved to a type

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the latest (4.x) version of these modules, they have been refactored a lot.
For example, the package name is now `org.apache.http.client`.
Old sample code will [have to be modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615394/migrating-from-httpclient-3-x-to-4-x?lq=1).
Look at the [Javadocs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html) and the [Quickstart](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html) for the new project.

The (discouraged) alternative would be to get the old (3.x) version.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) for managing your 3rd party dependencies. It takes care of jar files & all related dependencies.

The maven dependency for httpclient is:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
```